# Degree of exponential polynomial

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

What is the degree of the exponential polynomial :$$ e^x * (x^2 + x + 1)$$?

I am getting confused because of the exponential term there...

Comment: never heard of the word degree used in this situation.

Comment: It's a polynomial of degree $2$ times an exponential.  In what context are you trying to assign it a degree?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to solve integration of x^2*e^x using method of undetermined coefficients with A0, A1,A2....... previously, we had used this method for polynomials with degree <= 2.... was trying to apply the same logic here.... Analytically integrating x^2*e^x gives e^x*(x^2-2x+2)  ..... So thought if this is a polynomial of degree <= 2 or not.... So posted this question in that context..

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial then any anti-derivative of $P(x)e^x$ is $K+Q(x)e^x$ where $Q$ is a polynomial with $deg (Q)=deg (P)$. Use integration by parts  to prove this by induction on $deg (P). $ That is,  $\int e^xP(x)dx=$ $\int P(x)de^x=$ $e^xP(x)-\int e^xdP(x)=$ $e^xP(x)-\int e^xP'(x)dx.$

Comment: Thanks, Daniel and Christian, you both could perfectly figure out my point of confusion :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that one considers the vector space $V$ of all functions $f$ of the form $f(x)=e^x\,p(x)$, where $x\mapsto p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. This $V$  has dimension $3$. The operator $D:\>f\mapsto f'$ is linear, maps $V$ to itself, and has rank $3$, since $D(e^x\,x^k)=e^x q(x)$ is again in $V$, and $q$ is of degree $k$. It follows that $D:\>V\to V$ is nonsingular, in particular: surjective. This implies that any given function $f(x)=e^x(a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2)\in V$ is the derivative of some function $F(x)=e^x(b_0+b_1x+b_2 x^2)\in V$. The $b_k$ can be determined by comparing coefficients of $F'$ and the given $f$.